# Java Heap Space bytes available

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I need to know if there's a way in a Java program to know (as long variable) how many bytes I can use before getting a java heap space error while the program is running.
At the moment the only thing I can find is how to set it when running a program. That's not what I need.